# Add records to mysql database with php form without leaving/refreshing the page

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, forms

I use this file **input.php** to add record to database:

```
$order = "INSERT INTO wp_userdata
            (username, product_name, product_brand)
            VALUES
            ('$_POST[username]',
                        '$_POST[name]',
            '$_POST[brand]')";


$result = mysql_query($order);  
if($result){
    header( 'Location: http://page-with-form.php' ) ;
} else{
    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}
```

And my page with form **page-with-form.php**:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Add Products</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <form method="post" action="input.php">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="[insert_php]echo $username;[/insert_php]">
        <tr>
          <td>Product Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" size="50">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brand</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="brand" size="50">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"></td>
        </tr>
</form>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Everything works fine: When I click "Send" button, input.php adds record and redirects back to page-with-form.php. You can't even see input.php loading, however you do see the page-with-form.php getting refreshed.

Is there a way to make all the operation without refreshing the page-with-form.php? I think it has to do with Ajax, but maybe there is another way? looking forward for your suggestions!

Comment: yeah...you should use ajax if you dont want to refresh the page.

Comment: Yes. Ajax is what you want. Writing *yet another* Ajax tutorial is too broad for a stackoverflow question though.

Comment: Alternatively, use a normal form submission and issue a 204 No Content HTTP response if you don't want to update the view.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: This is a code I got from tutorial, didn't have a chance to modernize it - I am more concern with database functionality, I'll deal with baby stuff later

Comment: I will try to get it going in ajax and will post here if got into any obstacles, I indded don't want another tutorial here

Comment: A google search for "ajax form submit" turns up tons of great tutorials. Here's the top hit: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use AJAX to submit your form,

You can use JQuery to aid in this, the first thing you need to do is make sure your form does not refresh the page, and give your button an ID, this makes it easier to find the button through JQuery

first lets remove that line from your PHP code that causes a server side redirect, and instead have it produce a string stating that the data was saved succesfully, whatever this script prints in the HTTP response will be used by the ajax portion of this project

```
$order = "INSERT INTO wp_userdata
            (username, product_name, product_brand)
            VALUES
            ('$_POST[username]',
                        '$_POST[name]',
            '$_POST[brand]')";


$result = mysql_query($order);  
if($result){
    echo ("DATA SAVED SUCCESSFULLY");
} else{
    echo("Input data is fail");
}
```

Then lets modify the HTML to make it easier for Jquery to find the elements we need and output a status (this is not the only way, if you have multiple forms this is not recommended, Jquery has more sophisticated ways of finding form elements http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/ )

I just want to simply illustrate the idea rather then getting too much into Jquery details.

```
<table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td align="center">Add Products</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <!-- THIS TELLS THE FORM TO NOT REFRESH THE PAGE -->
            <form onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" id="hdn_username" value="[insert_php]echo $username;[/insert_php]">
            <tr>
              <td>Product Name</td>
              <td><input type="text" id="txt_name" name="name" size="50">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Brand</td>
              <td><input type="text" id="txt_brand" name="brand" size="50">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- THIS ROW WILL DISPLAY THE RESULT OF THE LAST ENTRY -->`
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><div id="status_text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td align="right">
                <!-- I GAVE THE BUTTON AN ID THAT WILL MAKE IT EASIER TO FIND WITH JQUERY -->
                <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" name="submit" value="Send"></td>
            </tr>
    </form>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

now for the Javascript version that will implement AJAX using the help of Jquery

What the Javascript will do is, when you click the button, it will post to your input.php and input PHP will return a result text.

```
//on the click of the submit button 
$("#btn_submit").click(function(){
 //get the form values
 var username = $('#hdn_username').val();     
 var name = $('#txt_name').val();     
 var brand = $('#txt_brand').val(); 

 //make the postdata
 var postData = 'username='+username+'&name='+name+'&brand='+brand;

 //call your input.php script in the background, when it returns it will call the success function if the request was successful or the error one if there was an issue (like a 404, 500 or any other error status)

 $.ajax({
    url : "input.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    success: function(data,status, xhr)
    {
        //if success then just output the text to the status div then clear the form inputs to prepare for new data
        $("#status_text").html(data);
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#brand').val('');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown)
    {
        //if fail show error and server status
        $("#status_text").html('there was an error ' + errorThrown + ' with status ' + textStatus);
    }
});
```

What should happen is, you enter data into your form and you will see a status appear of it being successful or an error, if successful the form will clear for you to add more input.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, Oluwakayode! I copied the text but for some reason when I click the button nothing happens.. here is the page http://suppliesprices.com/?page_id=4

Comment: I do not see the jquery library included on your page,
also, you need to close off the ondocument ready call, on line 66 you need another "});"

Comment: It's working now, thank you so much, its exactly what I was looking for! Can't believe wordpress page didn't load jquery on it's own, had to hardcode it to make it work. Now , is there a way to refresh the list printed out from the query on the same page to update to show new record added?

Comment: I tried the above code in simple hosting but it didn't work, when I hit send button nothing happens,

Answer (score 3):

you have to use ajax to insert data into mysql without page refreh

```
<form method='post' id='SaveForm' action="#">

<table class='table table-bordered'>

    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='name' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Employee Department</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='dept' ></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <button type="submit" name="btn-save" id="btn-save"></button>  
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

and the PHP code would be :

```
<?php
 if($_POST)
 {
    $emp_name = $_POST['name'];
    $emp_dept = $_POST['dept'];

    try{

     $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_employees(emp_name,emp_dept)   VALUES(:ename, :edept)");
     $stmt->bindParam(":ename", $emp_name);
     $stmt->bindParam(":edept", $emp_dept);

     if($stmt->execute())
     {
        echo "Successfully Added";
     }
     else{
     echo "Query Problem";
     } 
  }
    catch(PDOException $e){
       echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

?>
```

and the jquery ajax code is :

```
/* Data Insert Starts Here */
   $(document).on('submit', '#emp-SaveForm', function() {

    $.post("create.php", $(this).serialize())
    .done(function(data){
     $("#dis").fadeIn('slow', function(){
     $("#dis").html('<div class="alert alert-info">'+data+'</div>');
     $("#emp-SaveForm")[0].reset();
     }); 
   });   
  return false;
});
/* Data Insert Ends Here */
```

click the following link to get detailed article :

[jQuery Ajax Insert, Update and Delete with PHP MySQL](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/12/simple-jquery-insert-update-delete-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use ajax for achieving your goal Lets take example of this simple html form

```
<form id='myform' action='insert.php' method='post'>
  Name: <input type='text' name='name' />
  Address: <input type='text' name='address' />
</form>
```

And the php is

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address= $_POST['address'];
$sql = "insert into peoples (name,address) values('$name','$address')";
if(mysql_query($sql)){
   echo 'successfully inserted';
}else{
   echo 'could not insert';
}
```

And your Javascript with jQuery is

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){ return false; });
$('#submit').click(function(){
   $.post($('#myform').attr('action'),
   $('#myform :input').serializeArray(),
function(output){   $('#result').html(output); }); });
```

[For detailed description you check here](http://www.simplifiedcoding.net/2015/03/php-mysql-insert-into-database-without.html)

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
Button.click(function(){
 $.Ajax(
  Data: data,
  Success: 
   What you want to do on success
   Such as set HTML to div element
  )
 })
```

Just look up the jQuery API for Ajax, its all there.

Written on mobile so can expand answer later if you want me to.